# Invoke C++ method from VB.Net with string handled as string array

Tags: c++, vb.net, interop, marshalling

I have a C++ method with this signature:

```
STDMETHODIMP ClassName::FunctionName(long number, BSTR* names, long* status)
```

Inside the method the names variable is accessed as an array of strings, i.e.

```
char *  tempString = NULL;

for (int n = 0; n < number; n++)
{
    tempString = OLE2T(names[n]);
...
```

I compile the C++ project, which generates a dll, I then register this dll and add a reference to it in the VB project.
When I add the reference, an Interop assembly is automatically generated, and the signature of the method in the Interop assembly is as follows:

```
FunctionName (number as Integer, ByRef names as String) As Integer
```

From VB.Net I invoke the method like this:

```
result = FunctionName (number, names(0))
```

Where names is a string array with multiple elements, and number and result are Integers.

The problem is that when the C++ code tries to access the rest of the elements in the names array (names[1] and ahead) it starts getting "garbage" on those fields.

My question is, how do I send the whole string array instead of just the first value.

The C++ code is a library that I cannot modify, therefore any change that I do must be on the VB.Net code.

I was thinking that maybe using PInvoke to call the method might do the trick (declaring a correct signature), but I was hoping for something better.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit:

I'm no expert in Interop/Marshaling but I checked the IDL definition of the method and it is as follows:

```
[id(60), helpstring("method FunctionName")]
        HRESULT FunctionName(
                    [in] long number, 
                    [in, size_is(number)] BSTR* names,
                    [out, retval] long* status);
```

Shouldn't the size_is indicate that the names parameter is an array, and thus, when the Interop assembly is generated act accordingly?

Thanks again

Comment: You need some special IDL directives to tell the COM marshaller that `number` means the size of the string array `names`.  Otherwise the marshaller does not know this, and just expects independent values, not knowing that `names` is an array at all.

Of course you can write a C++ wrapper, which "knows" the invalid behavior of the original C++ library, and corrects the interface.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, I just edited the question with what I think is the idl information required as you say. Any advice?

Comment: VB doesn't have p/invoke or `MarshalAsAttribute`, perhaps you meant VB.net?  And `names[0]` isn't array element syntax in VB either?  The cleanest way to solve your problem would be with a C++/CLI wrapper that accepts a .NET `array<String^>`, converts to an array of `BSTR`, and then calls the C++ function.

Comment: Yes Ben, I'm referring to VB.Net, and the array thing was a typo, I just fixed it. So, there's no way to avoid this wrapper? I'd rather use Hans approach (manually editing the IL and generating a new Interop assembly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, [size_is] is an attribute that only midl.exe knows how to use.  It does so when it generates the proxy/stub for the interface, something that's used when you want to make the call across process boundaries.

It isn't otherwise expressible in a type library.  The argument gets emitted as "pointer to BSTR" which could either indicated a BSTR passed by reference or an array of BSTRs.  Tlbimp.exe can't tell the difference, it picks the former.  It has to, it cannot reasonably infer the array size.  You get junk at runtime because the CLR interop layer only passes a single element of the array.  Any COM client has a big problem using this method, it isn't .NET specific.  The .NET pinvoke marshaller has a workaround for this problem, note the SizeParamIndex property of the [MarshalAs] attribute.

If you cannot modify the C++ code then you'll need to edit the interop library by hand to inject that [MarshalAs] attribute.  That's quite fugly, you have to decompile the library with ildasm.exe, edit the .il and put it back together with ilasm.exe.  You don't want to do that often.

If you can then you should use the Automation compatible way to pass arrays.  Use a SAFEARRAY.  This is fully supported by type libraries and the CLR interop plumbing, no work on your end is needed on the managed side.  Also note that you now no longer need the *number* argument, safe arrays know how long they are.  Not unlike managed arrays.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, in case anyone is interested I modified the declaration of the method in the IL from this:  [in] string&  marshal( bstr) names) runtime managed internalcall  to this:  [in] string[]  marshal( bstr [0]) names) runtime managed internalcall.  This indicates that the parameter will be a string array and the length of the array will be the first argument of the method.